# Intellij - How do I use existing pom file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have downloaded some source code from the internet which contained a pom file.
I want to use its pom file rather than download each 3rd party jars.

How do I add pom file to my intellij project?
Can I set it to add the 3rd parties to my project?

Comment: You could have asked this question in the same question you asked about directory structures! Anyway, IDEA will detect that a pom.xml is present and do everything automagically for you

Comment: Thanks. I try to separate my questions when topics are different.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are using the later versions of IntelliJ you can File->Open and choose pom.xml to open. IntelliJ will setup a its project files according to the pom.xml and download the necessarily JARs.